# How to do codes for SAML/Azure AD in VB code after set up Single Sign-On with SAML in azure portal?

Tags: vbscript, azure-active-directory, saml

I have setup Single Sign-On with SAML in Azure portal but now I don't know how to do in VB codes. I need guidance on how to do in visual studio so that once I publish the web to cloud it can call SAML/Azure AD and redirect to login Microsoft and if login success will redirect to webapp.

Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Take a look. If you have any more query feel free to share here in comment. Thank you and happy coding!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit] your question to include what you've already tried, and which documentation you've looked at. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Answer (score 0):

Registering your app is just a way for Azure AD to know that your app wants to authenticate its users with AAD.

In your application, you will use one of the [many](https://www.componentpro.com/products/saml) SAML SDKs to integrate AAD authentication.